# Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in D:\wamp64\www\magento\includes\functions.php on line 1579

Tags: php, function, templates

I need a little help again... I get error mysql parameters, I know the problem but I cant find the missing parameters... this is the problem line

```
**`$result_template = mysqli_query($select_template) or die(mysql_error());`**
```

I know 1 parameter is missing but I dont know whichone?? Can you pls help me? Thanks

This is part of the codes maybe usefull....

```
/*function to display the active template*/


    function displayTemplate(){
        $tableprefix = "";
        global $tableprefix,$_SESSION;
        $template_array = array();

         $select_template = "SELECT vtop_filename,vleft_filename,vbottom_filename,vimages_folder,vcss_name,vtemplate_name
                            FROM ".$tableprefix."template_master WHERE vactive_status = 'Y'";

1579---->>>>   $result_template = mysqli_query($select_template) or die(mysql_error());

        $template_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_template);

        array_push($template_array,$template_row['vtop_filename'],$template_row['vleft_filename'],$template_row['vbottom_filename'],$template_row['vimages_folder'],$template_row['vcss_name'],$template_row['vtemplate_name']);

    return $template_array; 
    }
```

Comment: You beed ti pass the connection variable to the mysqli function

Comment: Sorry @Kinshuk I cant understand

Comment: you missed to the Connection object....Here is quick syntax ref `$res=mysqli_query($con_object,$query);`

Comment: `mysqli_query($conn,$select_template) ` ADD YOUR CONNECTION VARIABLE

Comment: You have set the mysqli_connect in some variable. Pass that variable to the function at the first position.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: con_object in D:\wamp64\www\magento\includes\functions.php on line 1579

Comment: also undefined variable $conn either

Comment: @Murat you took it in wrong sense...i meant the connection object that you have initialize something like `$con=mysqli_connect('servername/ip','username','password','databasename');
`then use
`$res=mysqli_query($con,$query);`

also these are syntax only you have to modify according to your need...

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc` != `mysqli_*`. Nor does `mysql_error()`.

Comment: Im really confuse I think... I cant fix this... try every think who says somethink here... but always got same message "undefined variable:" ! :(

Comment: I change the problem line like this $result_template = mysqli_query($select_template, $tableprefix) or die(mysqli_connect_error()); and finally avoid "undefined variable" error... but now I have new error...  Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in D:\wamp64\www\magento\includes\functions.php on line 1592  :(

Comment: Look at the manual. Parameter 1 connection, parameter 2 query.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell it where to connect to. Here is a simple example of working code to connect to a database from PHP.

```
 <php 

//Connect to DB 
$conn = new mysqli("Hostname","Username","Password","Database"); 

//If the connection has errors 
if ($conn->connect_error){ 
  //Display the error 
  die("Connection failed because: " . $conn->connect_error); 
} 

//Otherwise the connection is good so lets create a sql query 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Database"; 

//Get the results of the query 
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should refer the php documentation for this [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

As you are using the procedural style, so you will have to pass the mysqli_connect resource to your mysqli_query

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* Create table doesn't return a resultset */
if (mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myCity LIKE City") === TRUE) {
    printf("Table myCity successfully created.\n");
}

/* Select queries return a resultset */
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT Name FROM City LIMIT 10")) {
    printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", mysqli_num_rows($result));

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

/* If we have to retrieve large amount of data we use MYSQLI_USE_RESULT */
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM City", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) {

    /* Note, that we can't execute any functions which interact with the
       server until result set was closed. All calls will return an
       'out of sync' error */
    if (!mysqli_query($link, "SET @a:='this will not work'")) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

but as I can see that you are using it in some function so pass an object of db to this function and then use it in your mysqli_query